# Extract a list from a string using 're'

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a string in this format: `any_string = "[u'02', u'03', u'04', u'05']"`.
I want to extract a list from this which should look like `new_list = ['02', '03', '04', '05']`

I am using 're'. The below code i am writing to get this work done, but no luck

```
import re

new_list = re.findall(r'["w "]', any_string)
```

I am getting the result as `[' ', ' ', ' ']`

Basically I want a list like this `new_list = ['02', '03', '04', '05']`, so that i can loop through the individual items like `02, 03, 04 , 05`

Comment: `re.findall(r"'(\w+)'", any_string)` would work, but the `ast.literal_eval` solution is the best solution (short of getting the data in a more suitable format like json/yaml)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you aren't tied to `re`, what about `ast`? Just one more letter :)

```
In [1]: import ast

In [2]: any_string = "[u'02', u'03', u'04', u'05']"

In [3]: my_list = ast.literal_eval(any_string)

In [4]: type(my_list)
Out[4]: <type 'list'>

In [5]: my_list
Out[5]: [u'02', u'03', u'04', u'05']

In [6]: for item in my_list:
   ...:     print item
   ...:
   ...:
02
03
04
05
```

Comment: Basically i want a list like this new_list = ['02', '03', '04', '05'], so that i can loop through the individual items like 02, 03, 04 , 05

Comment: @sandeep So `ast.literal_eval()` will actually return the literal evaluation of your string, in this case a list. I'll drop in an example that will hopefully help.

Comment: Thanks a ton RocketDonkey, it works for me. But can we do it using 're'.

Comment: @sandeep Awesome, happy to hear it. As for the `re` solution, dbr actually posted it in a comment to your original post. If you need to use `re`, that expression would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I'd question where you are getting this string from. It looks like a list that has been passed through `str()` or `repr()`.  If you need to seralize a list into a string either use JSON or [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Ha, +1 for also suggesting a non-re option :)

Comment: :) I only use `re` if I have to.

Comment: This is **not** JSON string, this is Python list literal with unicode strings as elements. Using RocketDonkey's solution is really a lot better. However no downvote for trying.

Comment: You're right, though I still think they should focus on eliminating the need to parsing this string in the first place.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa: Apparently he has to, but you are correct in the part about moving to different format, if he is able to (eg. controls the code that generated the string). JSON is more popular and established as data exchange format.

Comment: Yeah its not a JSON string. RocketDonkey's solution works for me.